# Find conditional probability person has illness given X=x

Tags: self-study

10% of a city population has an illness that can be determined with a blood test. The amount of infection in blood sample of those who ARE NOT infected follows normal distribution with mean 20 and variance 1. Amount of infection in blood for those who ARE infected follows normal distribution with mean 25 and variance 1. If a person is drawn at random and amount of infection (X) in blood is measured:

What is conditional probability that person has the infection given X=x?

Comment: Hello and welcome to CV!  I see you've posted a homework question here.  Before your first post, we encourage you to read this topic:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.  Then please mark your question with the `self-study` tag.  Thanks and best of luck to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this seems to be a self-study question, I hope I can help out with some useful hints without performing any of the work for you.

First of all, I want to clear one thing out: given any point-value (in this case x) on a continuous scale, you can't calculate a probability; that point value is infinitely narrow.

You can calculate a probability for a given interval, however. Therefore, you first need to know if you want e.g. the probability given "x rounded up to a whole number" (i.e. x between 1-2, between 2-3, between 3-4 etc.) or something similar.

Usually, for a blood test, we'll have a certain cut-off value, anything above which indicates a (clinically) reasonable likelihood of infection.
So in this case, I think it's safe to assume that your question is best interpreted as >>what is the conditional probability of infection given a blood-test value of "x or higher"?<<

Now for a simple - and real-world applicable - way to find your answer (as in, this is how I, as a physician, will usually consider it).

Positive predictive value (PPV): This is the value, that you're looking for. It states that given a "positive" test answer ("x or higher"), this is the likelihood of true illness (that is, of actually carrying the infection).

What you need in order to calculate this are the sensitivity and the specificity of your test. Should be easy.

- Sensitivity is the likelihood of getting a positive test result, given true illness.
- Specificity is the likelihood of getting a NEGATIVE test result, given no ilness.

Sensitivity can be calculated from your distribution of the infected population:
What percentage of the total distribution has a value of x or higher.

Specificity can be calculated from your distribution of the non-infected population:
What percentage of the total distribution has a value of lower than x (i.e. "NOT x or higher").

Once you have your sensitivity and specificity, you can (together with the prevalence of the disease, which is 10%) use the to calculate the PPV:

```
PPV = (sens * prev) / ((sens * prev) + (1 - spec) * (1 - prev))
```

This formula shouldn't be too hard to derive, either, if you create a two-by-two table of individuals in the infected/non-infected and the positive/negative groups - this should help you visualise relationship between the probabilities of testing in a certain way, given an infection status, or of being infected, given a test answer.

I'll just go through it:

- The numerator (sens * prev) gives you the fraction of the total population with a TRUE positive test (that is, the percentage of the population with infection mutiplied by the percentages of those with a positive test).

You want to divide this by the fraction of the population which has ANY  positive tests (that is 'true positive fraction + false positive fraction'). The denominator is, therefore, the sum of just these.

1. True positives = (sens * prev)
2. False positives = (1 - spec) * (1 - prev)

- (1 - spec) = likelihood of getting a positive when not infected
- (1 - prev) = likelihood of being not infected

The wiki-page for predictive values in testing provides a quick overview, too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_predictive_values

Hope this helps.

ADDITION: If you're instead looking at X in interval blocks (rather than "x or higher"), you do pretty much the same.
Figure out the number of people in each block in each population (the area under the curve for that block multiplied by the prevalence), and divide the number of true positives (the AUC-infected) by the total positives (AUC-infected + AUC-noninfected).

Comment: Our Frank Harrell has some thoughts on sensitivity and specificity that are worth reading: https://www.fharrell.com/post/backwards-probs/.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps a lot!

Comment: @Dave, I hope that wasn't a jab at my answer being hopelessly convoluted ;) I enjoyed reading it, though I disagree with the notion that clinicians mix up the direction of probability; perhaps med students. I have, however, spent much time this pandemic explaining to the general public why they shouldn't accept great-sounding sens/spec declarations when (in some places) the predictive values of tests have often been <50% (and for a while here in Denmark even around 15-20%). I do, however, sometimes come across clinicians who think a p-value is "the likelihood that the null-hypothesis is true".

Comment: Just something I’ve had on my mind the past few days, nothing specific to your answer aside from bringing up sensitivity and specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Denote an infected individual by $I$ and a non-infected one by $\bar I$. From Bayes theorem,

$P(I|x)=\frac{P(x|I)P(I)}{P(x|I)P(I)+P(x|\bar I)P(\bar I)}$.

For continuous distributions, use their pdfs to replace the probabilities. With the given condition, we have

$P(I|x)=\frac{0.1\times e^{-0.5(x-25)^2}}{0.1\times e^{-0.5(x-25)^2}+0.9\times e^{-0.5(x-20)^2}}$.